# Android Studio layout for a 2d array

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to display a 9 by 9 array. 
The cells should be clickable.

It's pretty simple in java.

Which layout should I use in Android Studio?

```
int myArray[][] = new int [9][9]; // Previously filled with random numbers.

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
          System.out.print(" " + myArray[i][j]);
      }
      System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: You can use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to implement this:

1- Table layout and table row
2- Linear Layout

Linear layout performance is better than table layout and table row...

I would suggest you to use Linear Layout